# how to fix Symfony 3 FosrestBundle Invalid configuration, Warning: class_implements(): Class does not exist?

Tags: fosrestbundle, symfony-3.3

I am getting this error and didn't found the answer yet online,

How to fix this issue?

Invalid configuration for path "fos_rest.exception.codes": Warning: class_implements(): Class `� does not exist and could not be loaded

even though i used the same configuration which symfony recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved just by restarting the apache server.